# Google Cloud Build - Summary status shows FAILURE, all steps succeded

Tags: docker, google-cloud-build, google-container-registry

I've setup a Google Cloud Build pipeline that'll build a docker image from a Dockerfile, test the image and push the image into Google Container Registry.

Upon running the pipeline I noticed that all defined steps passed with `SUCCESS` status but the build summary itself returned with `FAILURE` status even though I can see the image being produced into Google Container Registry.

I used following command to build the image

```
gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yml --gcs-log-dir 'gs://<bucket>' .
```

and below is the error message returned:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) build www-xxxx-yyyy-zzzz completed with status "FAILURE"
 Error: The command exited with status 1
```

Is there any reason for the `gcloud builds submit` command to exit with code `1` as above if all the steps were marked as `SUCCESS`?

Below is some filtered log data taken from `gcloud builds describe` command for that specific build.

```
steps:
- args:
  - build
  - -t
  - <host>/<project/<image>:<tag>
  - .
  name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  status: SUCCESS
- args:
  - test
  - --image
  - <host>/<project/<image>:<tag>
  - --config
  - test_config.yml
  - -o
  - json
  name: gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/container-structure-test
  status: SUCCESS
```

Below is Google Cloud Build setup:

```
# cloudbuild.yml

steps:
# Build the image
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-t', '<host>/<project/<image>:<tag>', '.' ]
# Test the image
- name: 'gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/container-structure-test'
  args: [ 
    'test',
    '--image',
    '<host>/<project/<image>:<tag>',
    '--config',
    'test_config.yml',
    '-o',
    'json'
  ]

# Push the image
images: [ '<host>/<project/<image>:<tag>' ]
```

Comment: Is this being done in a local environment or is it being done on GCP? Asking because GCP should have audit logs, which often give more details on errors, as error 1 I believe is a generic error code.

Comment: Did you try to update your gcloud sdk version?

Comment: @fabc it was done on GCP, went thru all the log but can’t really draw anything for the summary level log. Logs for individual step is not showing any error too. Only the build summary that returned with ERROR status

Comment: @guillaume I haven’t tried it, I noticed there’s an update to gcloud CLI recently and maybe it comes with new SDK too. I’ll give it a go and see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Please let us know if you have tried updating the gcloud SDK version and if that solved the issue, so other users can benefit from your response in the future. Otherwise I will try to reproduce your case as much as you allow me to.

Comment: @acarrion I have just had another attempt with updated `gcloud` CLI without luck. Root cause is still not identifiable at this point and I am still running some analysis. Will post once there's an update.

Comment: I belong to the Google Cloud Platform Support group. Let me know if you want to share information so I can reproduce your issue in my own environment and investigate what could be the root cause.

Comment: @acarrion thank you coming forward, I have just finally resolved this issue by submitting a case support request that troubleshooted an error message in the back system where users/clients have no access to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've finally resolved this issue with the assistance of Google Cloud support team.

They found out a `403 Permission Denied` error as the Cloud Build container trying to access Google Cloud Storage to delete a certain log object stored in the bucket, this error message is found at the back system of Cloud Build where users/clients have no access to. The `403 Permission Denied` error is the result of the object retention policy applied to the bucket.

In my case, I've replaced retention policy with lifecycle policy to resolve this issue and it worked. We do this as we consider keeping Cloud Build log size under control is our primary objective and, to prevent any accidental deletion/modification to the log file, we ended up with setting read-only access to the resources in the log bucket except for the service account used by Cloud Build.

Comment: This same error appeared for me at the end of my Cloud Build logs as "BUILD FAILURE: Cloud Storage logging failed. Try again in a few minutes." This answer resolved it.

Comment: Would you mention how you replaced the retention policy with the lifecycle policy to resolve this issue?